# Join dataframes and merge/replace column values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
from delta.tables import *

vals1 = [(1, "a"), 
        (2, "b"), 
        (3, "c"), 
        (4, "d") 
      ]
columns1 = ["id","name"]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=vals1, schema=columns1)
# df1.show()

vals2 = [(1, "k"), 
        (2, "l"), 
        (3, "m")
      ]
columns2 = ["id","name"]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=vals2, schema=columns2)
# df2.show()

df1 = df1.join(df2, 'id', 'full')
df1.show()
```

Gives me the following result:

```
+---+----+----+
| id|name|name|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   a|   k|
|  3|   c|   m|
|  2|   b|   l|
|  4|   d|null|
+---+----+----+
```

How do I make it produce a single column for "name" that would contain "k, l, m, **d**" values?
(it has to always use values from df2, with one exception - when there is a row in df1 that doesn't have a matching row in df2, in this case it needs to use the value from df1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html).

```py
df1 = (df1.join(df2, 'id', 'left')
       .select('id', F.coalesce(df2.name, df1.name).alias('name')))
```

============================================================

**Update**

```py
df1 = (df1.join(df2, 'id', 'left')
       .select('id', 
               *[F.coalesce(df2[x], df1[x]).alias(x) for x in df1.columns if x != 'id' and x in df2.columns]))
```

============================================================

**Update2**

I think I understand your requirement. I tweak your sample data to illustrate your condition.

```
df1
id name
 1    a 
 2    b 
 3    c 
 4    d 

df2
id name
 1 null 
 2    l 
 3    m
```

If this is your input data, you should keep all values including the null (for id `1`) from `df2`, but you want the value `d` from `df1` because the id `4` is missing in `df2`.

Expected result should look like

```
id name
 1 null 
 2    l 
 3    m 
 4    d
```

In this case, there is no easy indicator to differentiate the null value where the null is from the original data or result from the outer merge.

One way to work around this is to replace the null value to something  else before the join and then replace back after the join.

```py
null_value = 'NA'
df2 = df2.na.fill(null_value)
df1 = (df1.join(df2, 'id', 'full')
       .select('id', 
               *[F.coalesce(df2[x], df1[x]).alias(x) for x in df1.columns if x != 'id' and x in df2.columns])
       .replace(null_value, None))
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply it to all the columns with matching names without adding them all to the call manually?

Comment: I updated.  something like that?  or use `matching = set(df1.columns).intersection(df2.columns)` to find the matching columns

Comment: Will try that, thanks. But there is another problem - when the value in df2 is null and in df1 is not, it preserves the value from df1 - and should use the value from df2 instead.

Comment: In your example, where df2 is null and df1 is "d", you wanted the "d" instead of null.   If this is not what you want, could you update your sample and expected output in question?

Comment: I want to preserve all the values with ids that exist in df1 and not in df2. But when there are values with matching ids, I always want to use the values from df2.

Comment: hmm, above code should pick df2's value unless it is null, and only pick df1's value when it is null (make sure the order is `df2[x], df1[x]` to give priority to df2).   could you apply to your data and show where it is failing?

Comment: I also need to pickup df2 values when they are null - if there is a matching row in df1, of course. In general, values from df2 should always be preferred when they exist.

Comment: Okay. I updated again.  Let me know if I understand your requirement correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

df_new (the new dataframe after joining df1 and df2)

```
df_1 = df_1.select(F.col('id'),F.col('name').alias('name_df1'))
df_2 = df_2.select(F.col('id'),F.col('name').alias('name_df2'))

df_new = df_1.join(df_2, on="id", how="outer") \
             .withColumn('name',F.coalesce('name_df2','name_df1')) \
             .select('id','name')
```

This is not the most efficient answer if you have a huge dataset, but this:

- Is more readable when you are trying to understand the steps
- Will get you the output you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution , use pyspark when case

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import when
#i have renamed cols from df2 to avoid ambiguity
>>> df_join = df1.join(df2,df1.id==df2.df2_id,"full")
>>>df_join1=df_join.withColumn("new_col",when(df_join.df2_name.isNull(),df_join.name).otherwise(df_join.df2_name))
>>> df_output=df_join1.select("id","name","new_col")
>>> df_output.show()
+---+----+-------+
| id|name|new_col|
+---+----+-------+
|  1|   a|      k|
|  3|   c|      m|
|  2|   b|      l|
|  4|   d|      d|
+---+----+-------+
```